# Pass array values from PHP to JavaScript using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP file which includes an array its data retrieved from the database.

this is the array in PHP file `dashboard.php`

```
echo $stat= json_encode(array( 
    0 => $posts['tot'], 
    1 => $partners['pap'], 
    2 => $messages['mem'], 
));
```

the output of this array will be: `["12","5","11"]`

on the other side, I have a javascript file which supposed to receive these data using ajax and after that output it into object data to be displayed in a chart on the `dashboard.php` page

this is ajax code in the javascript file:

```
function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'dashboard.php',
            type: 'get',
            data: { n1: n1, n2: n2, n3: n3 },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (response) {

                // selecting values from response Object
                var n1 = response.n1;
                var n2 = response.n2;
                var n3 = response.n3;
            }
        });
    });
```

I know there is something missing which how to define the data coming from the PHP file which this is my problem I couldn't figured it out.

I have looked into many tutorials but I'm still confused and I can't get it.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP output:

```
["12","5","11"]
```

All three values are clearly strings.

All you need to do is cast/convert them into number (using `intval` or similar) before being sent back to client-side:

```php
echo $stat = json_encode(array( 
    0 => intval($posts['tot']), 
    1 => intval($partners['pap']), 
    2 => intval($messages['mem']), 
));
```

Next, you have another problem where the server is passing back an array, but the client is trying to read it as if it's an object, hence you will never get the values.

Since the data being passed back to server is an array `["12","5","11"]`, in the client, you will want to retrieve it the array way:

```js
{
  ...otherAjaxOptions,
  success: function(response){
    var n1 = response[0];
    var n2 = response[1];
    var n3 = response[2];

    /* or using ES6 way */

    var [n1, n2, n3] = response;
  }
}
```

If the `response` is not an array, then your server is probably transforming the responses into a more structured object. In that case, simply check where the array is inside the `response`, and retrieve it the same way.

Comment: actually this not the main issue, the main problem how to read the passed values  from the php, somthing missing with ajax code which I can't figure it out

Comment: @nurialsj The same solution applies to client side. Just convert the strings you get from server into numbers.

Comment: yes I got what you mean, but my problem is that javascript doesn't read the passed values from PHP

Comment: @nurialsj You editted the question and I get what you mean now. See the updated answer.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name` i got this error in `function () {`

Comment: @nurialsj you need to type a name before `()`

Answer (score 0):

Consider redefining the keys of the associative array as required by the ajax script, namely 'n1', 'n2', 'n3'.

Remove the closing parenthesis and semicolon after ajax and rewrite ajax into a function that returns response from success function handler.

Also return the result of ajax call from function after naming the function, right now it is an anonymous unnamed function.  Unless you want to invoke using an Immediate Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)  then use

```
(function(){})();
```

**index.html**

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Ajax</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <script>
        function ajax() {
          return $.ajax({
            url: 'dashboard.php'
          }).done(function(response) {
              // selecting values from response Object
              var n1 = response.n1;
              var n2 = response.n2;
              var n3 = response.n3;
              return response;
            });
        }
        $('document').ready(function(){  
            ajax().then(function(result){
              $("body").html("<pre>"+result+"</pre>");
            });
          });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php
    $posts = [];
    $partners = [];
    $messages = [];

    $posts['tot'] = '12';
    $partners['pap'] = '5';
    $messages['mem'] = '11';


    echo json_encode(array( 
        'n1' => $posts['tot'], 
        'n2' => $partners['pap'], 
        'n3' => $messages['mem'] 
    ));
```

**See demo on glitch**
[https://glitch.com/~twilight-glow-cheque](https://glitch.com/%7Etwilight-glow-cheque)

Comment: actually, it read the value from three tables in the database and each value it gets it as a number then but all of them in one array and after that encoded JSON file to pass it to the javascript file. so the problem is in the javascript file couldn't read these values, you can check the ajax code mentioned in the question